# How to overcome ImportError: cannot import name XXXX

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have pulled some working Django code from a repo and am trying to set up my local windows 7 dev environment. I have what I think is a suitable version of Python (2.7.6) and a copy of Django 1.5.4.

When I tried `python manage.py runserver`, I got various ImportErrors.

One by one, I did a `pip install XXXX` and they went away.

But now I am stuck with this error;

ImportError: cannot import name parse_html_config

I'm only a few days into Python & Django so am unclear - but I think this import is part of commandtools package, so I did `pip install commandtools`. I got the message that commandtools was already installed.

When I search my project, I can't find `from XXXX import parse_html_config` anyway, so I don't know where to look next, can anyone help please?

The whole output is;

```
(swoopenv) C:\django workspace\swoopenv\swoop\swoop>python manage.py runserver
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:465: DeprecationWarning: The 'execute_manager' function is deprecated, you
likely need to update your 'manage.py'; please see the Django 1.4 release notes (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/).
  DeprecationWarning)
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:409: DeprecationWarning: The 'setup_environ' function is deprecated, you li
kely need to update your 'manage.py'; please see the Django 1.4 release notes (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/).
  DeprecationWarning)
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py:221: DeprecationWarning: You have no filters defined on the 'mail_admins' logging hand
ler: adding implicit debug-false-only filter. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#request-exceptions-are-now-always-logge
d
  DeprecationWarning)
ImportError: cannot import name parse_html_config
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the traceback? What's trying to import it, and where's it looking?

Comment: I have edited and added this, but I don't know how to get more detail in the traceback...

Comment: Seems likely that your project is expecting a version of Django prior to 1.4. Is it a public project - can you link post a link to the repo?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Is there anything I can look for in the codebase to tell me version? Or anything I can execute on production server to find out version of django that is running please?